# WebRTC : Coturn server works fine but videos are not transferred

Tags: webrtc, coturn

I'm hosting a video call site on Heroku [here](https://mylivingroom.herokuapp.com/rooms). My coturn server is Docker-containerized and runs locally behind a router. I opened all the needed ports (3478, 40000-65535) so that I am sure that the corturn server works over the Internet because I checked it using [Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).

Everything is fine except the video is not transferred when two devices are not on the same network. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code is using the TURN server?

You need to pass the `iceServers` list with the TURN URL and correct credentials. See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/setConfiguration

Then when you start the ICE gathering, you should see in coturn's log whether the Allocate Request was correctly handled and a XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS returned.

But you can also see it on the client side (the laptop where the browser runs) by launching a tool like Wireshark and selecting `stun` as filter.

In addition, when the call is up, check in chrome://webrtc-internals whether ICE gathering has provided `relay` candidates.